# Why is my macro not scraping as expected?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using the macro below to scrape a site. When I run through the macro using F8 it works fine but when I run it normally it skips out scraping the information at these lines:-

```
            Cells(r, 1).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehiclegroup")
           Cells(r, 2).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehicletransmission")
           Cells(r, 3).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehicletitle")
           Cells(r, 4).Value = entry.getAttribute("datstandardwaiverratefee")
           Cells(r, 5).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-superwaiverratefee")
           r = r + 1
```

The macro skips scraping the information when i = 1, 3 and 5. I do not understand why it is doing this or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Sub car()


        Dim appIE As Object
        Dim e As Object
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim o
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String
        Dim c As String
        Dim d As String
        Dim PickUp As Object
        Dim iL As IHTMLElement
        Dim f As IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim post As Object
        Dim Ret As Object
        Dim entry As Object
        Dim l As Object


    r = 2

        Set wb = Application.Workbooks("car3")
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Open internet explorer
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")


    'Navigate to site
    With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.car.co.za"
    .Visible = True

    Do While appIE.busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

      For i = 1 To 6


        With ws
    a = .Cells(i, 8)
    d = .Cells(i, 9)
    b = .Cells(i, 10)
    c = .Cells(i, 11)
    End With

       Do While appIE.busy And e Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop

     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("PickupBranch_BranchID_id")
      For Each o In e.Options
        If o.Value = a Then
            o.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Do While appIE.busy And e Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop


    Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("ReturnBranch_BranchID_id")


    For Each o In e.Options

        If o.Value = d Then
            o.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Do While appIE.busy And f Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Loop


    Set f = appIE.document.getElementById("timepicker-pickup").getElementsByTagName("li")

    For Each iL In f
      If iL.innerText = "09" Then
      iL.Click
      Exit For
      End If
    Next iL

    Do While appIE.busy And post Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Loop

    Set post = appIE.document.getElementsByName("PickupDate")

    'Looping through multiple values:
    For Each post In appIE.document.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
    post.Value = b
    Next post

    Do While appIE.busy And Ret Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Loop

    Set Ret = appIE.document.getElementsByName("ReturnDate")

    'Looping through multiple values:
    For Each Ret In appIE.document.getElementsByName("ReturnDate")
    Ret.Value = c
    Next Ret

    'Clicking Book now button
    Do While appIE.busy And l Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
        Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
    If l.className = "btn search-btn" Then
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        Next

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

        On Error Resume Next
        Do While appIE.busy And entry Is Nothing
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        DoEvents
        Loop
      'Scraping information



    For Each entry In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("filtered-vehicles")(0).getElementsByClassName("vehicle box-shadow-dark-2")


        Cells(r, 6).Value = i
        Cells(r, 1).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehiclegroup")
       Cells(r, 2).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehicletransmission")
       Cells(r, 3).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-vehicletitle")
       Cells(r, 4).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-standardwaiverratefee")
       Cells(r, 5).Value = entry.getAttribute("data-superwaiverratefee")
       r = r + 1

    Next entry

    .Navigate "https://www.car.co.za"
    .Visible = True

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Do While appIE.busy
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop



    r = r + 2


    Next i

    End With

    appIE.Quit
        Set appIE = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to get into the habit of naming your variables something meaningful. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need application.wait in this loop;

```
Do While appIE.busy
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Loop
```

It will wait until site is fully loaded. As about your question, I guess that the website fires some scripts when your macro is doing the job. You can either add Do While appIE.busy Loop between your 'For Each entry' loop or just something  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")).

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation I found that putting:-
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) before the For each entry sorted the problem out1